# How to utilise country codes stored in a variable when using Open Weather API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, validation, dom

I have stored country codes in a variable (i.e. GB, USA, NZ) that I acquired from https://restcountries.eu/

I'm also using free Weather API https://openweathermap.org/api to fetch current weather data for whatever town user puts into my search input.

Everything works fine, but the problem I'm having is integrating the country codes and linking them up to checkboxes for users to click & filter their search to the particular town (for example there is Manchester in both UK and the USA, and the search by default will only show UK one). 
Is there any way to utilise the stored country codes in a variable to present them in a form of a checkboxes (or something similar) for the user to choose from? I will probably need to write some HTML to present the checkboxes etc but I'm not understanding how to efficiently use the variable with stored codes and what would be a smart thing to do in this case.

I have created a new variable with the GB code as a string, and made my getJSON take that into the parameters of the search, the same way it takes in the search input to query a particular town. That worked, but instead of writing 20+ country codes manually I was wondering if there's an elegant solution to my problem.
I have also played around with some if statements (that you can see below) but I'm aware that's some primitive/poor quality code.

```
        var city = $("input[name=city-box]").val();
        var region = "";

        if (document.getElementById("GB").checked) {
            region = ",gb";
        }
        if (document.getElementById("USA").checked) {
            region = ",usa";
        }

        $.getJSON("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + city + region + "&units=metric&APPID=apikey", function(data) {
            console.log(data);.....
```

This sort of accomplishes what I'm trying to do (albeit poorly) and its not utilising those country codes stored for me in a different variable. Any advice appreciated!

Comment: Checkboxes are good for checking multiple options, good for few options. Use drop down instead because the user should not be able to select multiple countries or cities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example showing one way of doing it using `<select>` elements and the `change` event¹:

```js
$(function() {
    var countryCodes = ["GB", "US", "NZ"];
    var cities = ["Manchester", "Birmingham"];

    var countrySelect = $("#country-box");
    var citySelect    = $("#city-box");

    // Add country codes/cities to the <select> elements
    populateSelectElement(countrySelect, countryCodes);
    populateSelectElement(citySelect, cities);

    // Listen for the "change" event on the .weather-select elements
    $(".weather-select").change(function() {
        var countryCode = countrySelect.val();
        var city = citySelect.val();

        // Ensure both a country and city have been selected before making a request
        if (countryCode && city) {
            var apiUrl = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + city + countryCode + "&units=metric&APPID=apikey";
            console.log("Loading URL: " + apiUrl);
        }
    })

    // Adds <option> elements to an element from an array
    function populateSelectElement(element, values) {
        for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            element.append("<option value='" + values[i] + "'>" + values[i] + "</option>");
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<select id="country-box" class="weather-select">
    <option value="">Select a country</option>
</select>

<select id="city-box" class="weather-select">
    <option value="">Select a city</option>
</select>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Obviously this is quite basic, but should be enough to give you an idea.

---

¹ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event